# Java client library for reading from Kestrel server Queue from within Storm Spout

Tags: apache-storm, kestrel

I've setup a Kestrel server and able to setup and use queues via the python [pykestrel](https://github.com/empower/pykestrel) library.

We have a scenario where a python client writes to Kestrel queue(s) and a Storm spout needs to read from the queue(s).
I've tried using the storm-kestrel library but running into issues. Googling seems to suggest it doesn't support the memcache port (22133).

I've added the maven bindings as provided [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-kestrel). Didn't use the KestrelThriftSpout spout, using Kestrel.Client. Compilation is fine but I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error at runtime.

STACK TRACE

```
1098 [main] ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn  - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lnet/lag/kestrel/thrift/Kestrel$Client;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1659)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:480)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1133)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.serialize(Utils.java:52)
    at backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder.createTopology(TopologyBuilder.java:94)
    at com.rr.storm.ArticleTolopolgy.main(ArticleTolopolgy.java:35)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.lag.kestrel.thrift.Kestrel$Client
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 15 more
```

Can someone please confirm if storm-kestrel can or cannot be used in this scenario?

If not, is there another kestrel client library that is recommended to be used from within a storm spout for reading data off of kestrel queue(s)?

Comment: Would you please post the error message you got?

Comment: And how you configured your Spout to read from Kestrel?

Comment: I added the bindings to maven as specified here: https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-kestrel. It compiles fine but gives the dreaded Java NoClassDefFound error at runtime. I'm new to storm and Java so troubleshooting is being tough.

Comment: Seriously, I can't help without stacktraces (reasonable ones) and your Spout

Comment: I'll add those the moment I get back to work. I assume you're saying that the storm-kestrel library works for this scenario and it's just an error on my side? Thanks Chiron.

Comment: It is a problem with my classpath settings at runtime. I've moved to a simpler kestrel library in the process and would post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late update.

- The java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError was because some JARs were not in classpath. There were several dependencies involved so we resolved the issue by packing all dependencies into a SINGLE JAR. There were several dependency conflicts that needed to be resolved esp. a nasty one involving AWS SQS and storm depending on different httpclient libraries. Required downgrading the AWS SQS Java SDK version to 1.4.7 instead of the latest 1.7.2 at the time of posting.
- It doesn't look like the [storm-kestrel](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-kestrel) library works with the kestrel server anymore but someone else can correct if the understanding is wrong.
- Used [pykestrel](https://github.com/matterkkila/pykestrel) for Python client and it works great.
- Used [simple-kestrel-client](https://github.com/hogelog/simple-kestrel-client) for Java kestrel client (Storm spout) and it works great
- Used Java SDK [v1.4.7](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.4.7) for AWS SQS due to the conflict and it works great.

Comment: We're using storm-kestrel 0.7.2-SNAPSHOT with kestrel 2.4.1 via thrift with no issues.

Comment: Thanks Angelo. Should have been clearer. I was looking for the memcached client and couldn't get it to work.