# Problems running Storm with additional classpath

Tags: java, apache-storm

**How can I run storm topology with additional classpath?**

My output directory is as follows:

1. myapp.jar (The manifest's classpath contains the config & lib dir)
2. lib  - (directory)
3. conf -(directory)

**There are the following solutions for this problem (which are not good for me- I don't think it's best practice):**

1. pack those files within the jar.
2. Put those files in storm lib.

*ref: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/YqNr82Y3Nac*

Comment: We build a single Jar with dependencies and that's been doing pretty well.

Comment: Hey Vishal, thanks for your answer. 
I know that it's possible to pack those things together. but I want to remove the dependency between the config files, external libs to my app code.

Comment: We tried quite a few things before settling on this and even then ran into a lot of dependency conflict issues that were painful to resolve.      Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580323/java-client-library-for-reading-from-kestrel-server-queue-from-within-storm-spou

Comment: Thanks for your answer (Even so it, isn't so helpful :-) )

Comment: You're right, just didn't find a better way so hopefully someone with more experience will provide an answer that we may use too.. :-)

Answer (score 2):

There is no (clean) way (that I am aware of) to extend the classpath of the storm workers.  Apart from the topology jar itself, the classpath is defined at JVM start-up => anything present there is visible to (thus is shared by) all topologies running on each node. Moreover, because of the cluster nature of storm, putting topology-specific files on the filesystem of storm worker would render your deployment a bit trickier to deploy since you have to copy/update those topology-specific files to every node. The Storm Deployer is meant to hide that from us.

Bundling dependant jars into myapp.jar worked well for me so far since it makes sure my dependencies are always deployed and updated in every node. Bundling config files there technically works as well, but that renders myapp.jar environment-specific which is indeed not a best practise.

I usually copy any supplementary config file in the node from where I do deployment (not the nodes where the topologies are running), serialise them in a json-friendly format and add them to the Storm config at deployment time. Like that I can read them again from any prepare() method anytime my topology starts on some node of the cluster. Here again, this approach makes me sure that my config is present and up to date in any node of my cluster.

Comment: Please see the link below on how to add dependent jar files and configuration files in the single jar http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-5things6/index.html

Comment: @Niranjan, I think the author of the question knows how to do that, he mentioned it his text. In fact, putting dependencies in the deployed jar is the default way of proceeding in Storm, with a simple "maven with dependencies" approach. 
I understand the question is about finding other ways to extends the classpath, which is what I discuss, and discourage, in my response.

Answer (score 1):

The script `${STORM_HOME}/bin/storm.py`, which gets invoked after you run the `storm` command, picks up the environment variable `STORM_EXT_CLASSPATH` and adds it to the classpath.

Setting that environment variable should solve your problem:

```
export STORM_EXT_CLASSPATH={myoutput_dir}/lib
```

**Follow up:** this doesn't work because of a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/STORM-1026) in `storm.py` where `STORM_EXT_CLASSPATH` doesn't get added properly - each individual character in `STORM_EXT_CLASSPATH` gets added instead of the entire string (even if you use square brackets, quotes, etc.)

Comment: How does this answer the question? The question is not about python.

Comment: The question is not about python: true; but when you run `storm`, you actually runs a `.py` script, and in the script it tries to load the `STORM_EXT_CLASSPATH` and set it as your jar's classpath, so yes, we have to deal with python

Answer (score 1):

It seems since 2014 storm has also identified this problem and has a solution now (I'm using version `1.1.1`).

See the doc: http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.1.1/Command-line-client.html

> Syntax: storm jar topology-jar-path class ...
>
> Runs the main method of `class` with the specified arguments. The storm
>   jars and configs in `~/.storm` are put on the classpath. The process is
>   configured so that StormSubmitter will upload the jar at
>   `topology-jar-path` when the topology is submitted.
>
> When you want to ship other jars which is not included to application
>   jar, you can pass them to `--jars` option with comma-separated string.
>   For example, `--jars
>   "your-local-jar.jar,your-local-jar2.jar"`
>   will load `your-local-jar.jar` and `your-local-jar2.jar`. And when you
>   want to ship maven artifacts and its transitive dependencies, you can
>   pass them to `--artifacts` with comma-separated string. You can also
>   exclude some dependencies like what you're doing in maven pom. Please
>   add exclusion artifacts with '^' separated string after the artifact.
>   For example, `--artifacts "redis.clients:jedis:2.9.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.2^org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12"` will load `jedis` and `kafka` artifact and all of transitive dependencies but exclude `slf4j-log4j12` from `kafka`.

Answer (score 0):

**O.K. so I have a solution. I am not sure if it's good enough (since it's a little bit complicated) but whatever...** 
*(If you have other solutions, they will be welcomed :-) )*

Steps:

1. Use CMDB (Configuration management DB) for example puppet.
2. Set the config and/or dependencies at the needed locations using (CMDB).
3. Load this resources dynamically (within your code) and add them to your your classpath. The resource location will be taken via JVM parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When submitting your topology with the `storm jar` command, Storm will look in the ~/.storm directory and add any files in that directory to the classpath. This is the method I have used to not have to pack my dependent jars into the main one that I submit to Storm.

See also [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24617915/534347).

From the [documentation](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Command-line-client.html):

> jar Syntax: storm jar topology-jar-path class ...
>
> Runs the main method of class with the specified arguments. The storm
>   jars and configs in ~/.storm are put on the classpath. The process is
>   configured so that StormSubmitter will upload the jar at
>   topology-jar-path when the topology is submitted.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to storm framework and was facing the same problem. I am using storm apache-storm-0.9.2-incubating version and testing it on windows machine. I have few external jars which I wanted to get added in storm classpath without putting them under ${STORM_HOME}/lib or ${STORM_HOME}/conf directory. To achieve this i have modified the **${STORM_HOME}/bin/storm-config.cmd** file and added below new variable which will point to the external jar location(In my case it's C:\storm-installation\topology\custom-jars)

set STORM_BIN_DIR=%STORM_HOME%\bin
set STORM_CUSTOM_DIR=C:\storm-installation\topology\custom-jars

Modify below line in the same file to append all external jars to classpath as below.

set CLASSPATH=!CLASSPATH!;%STORM_HOME%\lib*
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%STORM_CUSTOM_DIR%*

Now if you check the storm classpath by using **%STORM_HOME%\bin\storm classpath** command, your external jars should show in class path.

Hope it helps to you.

Comment: See below; now we have an official(and nicer) solution.