# Insert rows into HBase from a Storm bolt

Tags: java, hbase, apache-storm

I would like to be able to write new entries into HBase from a distributed (not local) Storm topology. There exist a few GitHub projects that provide either [HBase Mappers](https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-hbase) or [pre-made Storm bolts](https://github.com/jrkinley/storm-hbase/wiki/HBase-Storm-Bolts) to write Tuples into HBase. These projects provide instructions for executing their samples on the LocalCluster.

The problem that I am running into with both of these projects, and directly accessing the HBase API from the bolt, is that they all require the HBase-site.xml file to be included on the classpath. With the direct API approach, and perhaps with the GitHub ones as well, when you execute `HBaseConfiguration.create();` it will try to find the information it needs from an entry on the classpath.

How can I modify the classpath for the storm bolts to include the Hbase configuration file?

**Update: Using danehammer's answer, this is how i got it working**

Copy the following files into your ~/.storm directory:

- hbase-common-0.98.0.2.1.2.0-402-hadoop2.jar
- hbase-site.xml
- storm.yaml  :   NOTE: if you do not copy storm.yaml into that directory, then the storm jar command will NOT use that directory in the classpath (see the [storm.py python script](https://github.com/apache/incubator-storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/multilang/py/storm.py) to see that logic for yourself - would be nice if this was documented)

Next, in your topology class's main method get the HBase Configuration and serialize it:

```
final Configuration hbaseConfig = HBaseConfiguration.create();
final DataOutputBuffer databufHbaseConfig = new DataOutputBuffer();
hbaseConfig.write(databufHbaseConfig);
final byte[] baHbaseConfigSerialized = databufHbaseConfig.getData();
```

Pass the byte array to your spout class through the constructor. The spout class saves this byte array to a field (Do not deserialize in the constructor. I found that if the spout has a Configuration field you will get a cannot serialize exception when running the topology)

in the spout's open method, deserialize the config and access the hbase table:

```
Configuration hBaseConfiguration = new Configuration();
ByteArrayInputStream bas = new ByteArrayInputStream(baHbaseConfigSerialized);
hBaseConfiguration.readFields(new DataInputStream(bas));
HTable tbl = new HTable(hBaseConfiguration, HBASE_TABLE_NAME);

Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("cf"), Bytes.toBytes("YOUR_COLUMN"));

scnrTbl = tbl.getScanner(scan);
```

Now, in your nextTuple method you can use the Scanner to get the next row:

```
Result rsltWaveform = scnrWaveformTbl.next();
```

Extract what you want from the result, and pass those values in some serializable object to the bolts.

Comment: plus one for not deserializing the byte array in the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a topology with the "storm jar" command, the `~/.storm` folder will be on the classpath (see [this link](http://storm.incubator.apache.org/documentation/Command-line-client.html) under jar command). If you placed the hbase-site.xml file (or related *-site.xml files) in that folder, `HBaseConfiguration.create()` during "storm jar" would find that file and correctly return you an `org.apache.hadoop.configuration.Configuration`. This would need to be stored and serialized within your topology in order to distribute that config around the cluster.

Comment: are you saying that you would create the HBaseConfiguration inside of the topology class then serialize it and pass it to the bolt somehow (perhaps in the setBolt(...).addConfiguration method?